# How do I add this code (txt file) into my class __init__ section?

Tags: python, class

Using Python. I have a class with 4 functions (addStudent, showStudent, deleteStudent, searchStudent), and am pulling from a database from a .txt file.

I have this code at the beginning of every function:

```
data = "studentMockData_AS2.txt"
        students = []

        with open(data, "r") as datafile:
                for line in datafile:
                    datum = line.split()
                    students.append(datum)
```

I tried to add it into the def **init**() part of my class to avoid having it in every function, but this isn't working. Mostly getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'students'`. This is how it looks:

```
class Student(): 

def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = "studentMockData_AS2.txt"
    self.students = []
    with open (data, 'r') as datafile:
        self.content = datafile.read()
        for line in datafile:
            self.datum = line.split()
            self.students.append(self.datum)

def SearchStudent(self):
    if self == ('byId'):
        searchId = input('Enter student id: ')
        
        for self.datum in self.students:
            if self.datum[0] == searchId:
                print(self.datum)
            # the rest of the code
```

Comment: `SearchStudent(self)` is a method without argument (The self is the instance itself and is python default. It seems that you have called the function with an argument, which seems to case the error. Please provide a [Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You almost certainly mean `self.data = data`. If the file isn't used after `__init__` completes, there's no need to save the filename as an instance attribute anyway.

Comment: For future posts, or even this one, pay close attention to how you indent your code in the question. A change of indent may make it hard to catch the purpose/hierarchy of your code ..

Comment: From a design standpoint, don't make `Student.__init__` responsible for opening the file. It's more flexible to accept any file-like object or even a plain iterator, and let the caller decide if it will use a file, `io.StringIO`, a plain list of strings, etc, as the argument.

Comment: I mean, there are many points in the design that are strange. e.g. `self.datum` is overwritten in every iteration and re-assigned in the loop of the search function. Let alone the use of `input` within a function body...

Answer (score 0):

There is something going wrong with your function `SearchStudent`. You may want to pass an extra parameter OR to use a class member variable to compare to the string `'byId'`.

In the case the if condition passes (i.e.: `self == 'byId'` is true), then your class reference `self` is a string. So it is normal it does not have the members you request.

```
class Student(): 

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = "studentMockData_AS2.txt"
        self.students = []
        with open (data, 'r') as datafile:
            self.content = datafile.read()
            for line in datafile:
                self.datum = line.split()
                self.students.append(self.datum)

    # notice the new parameter here
    def SearchStudent(self, rtype):
        if rtype == ('byId'):
            searchId = input('Enter student id: ')
            
            for self.datum in self.students:
                if self.datum[0] == searchId:
                    print(self.datum)
                # the rest of the code
```

Comment: Don't overwrite/shadow builtin `type`

Comment: Yep, I realised my mistake just as you were posting your comment, nice catch though!

Comment: Shadowing `type` is only a problem if you planned on using the built-in in your function. It's not going to break *any* other code that might be using `type`; that's why function-local scopes exist.